# Google Script - Clear Range except one specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, range

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v4SrxT5voa94gXxjlEtNm69TNTq3cCbRlHymO_5jjic/edit?usp=sharing

I'm having a hard time writing a simple apps script in Google Sheets that clears all values except a specific value. Sample sheet above. The ideal solution would clear all of row "C" or at minimum clear values "C4:C" or "C4:C100" except cells with the word/value "DELIVER". The script below has been working, the problem is that the script needs constant updating as the rows are not fixed and change based on business needs. So a fixed set of ranges is not ideal. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
function ClearAztecaFOODForm() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['C4:C16', 'C19:C28', 'C31:C42']).activate()
  .clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Description**

You could get column C and replace any value that is not DELIVER with blank.  In my example script I get all values from column C starting from row 4 and use an Array method forEach() to replace the values.  Then I put column C back.

**Code.gs**

```
function ClearAztecaFOODForm() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("COPYAztecaFOOD");
    let range = sheet.getRange(4,3,sheet.getLastRow()-3,1)
    let values = range.getValues();
    values.forEach( row => { if( row[0] !== "DELIVER" ) row[0] = "" } );
    range.setValues(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
};
```

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [try{} catch(){} block](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)
- [SpreadsheetApp.getUi()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getUi())

Comment: One piece of advise.  If you had formulas in column C when you would setValues() all the formulas would be erased.  There is a way around that but that's a story for another time.

Comment: Excuse my follow up question, I understand most of the script, but I do not understand this part of the code in LINE 5 --> sheet.getLastRow()-3,1)

Comment: `sheet.getLastRow()` will return the row number of the last cell in that sheet containing data, let say you have values in A1:C10 so it would return 10.  In `getRange()` the third parameter is number of rows to get.  Since we start at 4 you need to subtract 3 from 10 to get only 7 rows of data. `getRange(4,3,sheet.getLastRow()-3,1` would get values starting from row 4, column C, 7 rows, 1 column.